# Send data from activity A to B multiple times before launch B and display all data send

Tags: android

I want to send data from activity A to activity B without launch B when button press on activity A.This must happend multiple times (multiple button clicks) and I want to store all the information so when I launch activity B, I want to display all items I have send in a listView.
I'm having problems here and I'm only saving last button click.

Here is my activity A code:

```
public class GameDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    String gameTitle;
    String gamePrice;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        gameTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("GameTitle");
        gamePrice = getIntent().getStringExtra("GamePrice");


        FloatingActionButton botonAddToCart = findViewById(R.id.floatingButtonAddToCart);
        botonAddToCart.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("GameTitleCart", gameTitle);
        editor.putString("GamePriceCart", gamePrice);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

And activity B code:

```
public class Carrito extends AppCompatActivity {                

    List<String> gameTitle = new ArrayList<String>();           
    List<String> gamePrice = new ArrayList<String>();   

    @Override                                                 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);        
     Map<String, ?> allEntries = prefs.getAll(); 
     for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()){         
         if(entry.getKey() == "GameTitleCart"){         
             gameTitle.add(entry.getValue().toString());
         }                                              
         else if (entry.getKey() == "GamePriceCart"){   
             gamePrice.add(entry.getValue().toString());
     }                                           

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, gameTitle, gamePrice);            
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);               
}
```

Activity A is launched at another activity trigger so I handle the data with Intent.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: you want to paas a list of data from Activity A To B when button click or what you want your question is a little bit messy. It doesn't convey what you want to do. please clearify here

Comment: Sorry. In Activity B I have a listView ideally with multiple entries, empty at first. The data I show in the listView are Lists _gameTitle_ and _gamePrice_. I am trying to fill these lists by pressing a button in activity A. When I press the button in activity A, I send 1 _gameTitle_ and 1 _gamePrice_, so if I press the button 2 times, I want to have 2 entries in B, which correspond to 2 gameTitle and 2 gamePrice.
But this does not work and I only save the data of the last button press.

Answer (score 0):

On activity A you can store your data into an array and then when you want to start activity B just pass that array into intent by putExtra